# Ssh and Nat forwarding

Tags: networking, ssh, nat

New here and also in dealing with networks. First I'd like to apologise if my post is looking messy, cos I typed and copied everything and in the texting box is looking nice but the preview is very messy.

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi (with Ubuntu Server) as a backup server and because I want it to work wherever I am I decided to use Dynu to have a hostname and not depend on checking my public IP all the time. However I am struggling to make it work.

I can connect all machines to each other using the private ips when I am in my internal network (as expected). So the next step was configure my router to forward external ports into the machines (I have a Windows notebook with WSL Ubuntu, a second notebook with Solus Linux, a virtual machine and another Pi, both with Ubuntu). For the sake of simplicity, here are the addresses:

```
Windows:             192.168.1.199 -> Port: 2199
Virt. Ubuntu:        192.168.1.103 -> Port: 2103
Rasp. Pi server:     192.168.1.111 -> Port: 2111
Rasp. Pi desktop:    192.168.1.105 -> Port: 2105
Solus:               192.168.1.109 -> Port: 2109
```

Thus, if I want to connect to the server I need to type username@hostaddress -p 2111. And it works only when I am out of my network (I use my phone as a hotspot). But wasn't it supposed to work independently of the network?

Comment: I will try to post the logs tomorrow as I am getting a message saying that it is looking like spam

Comment: Lemme know guys if this is working: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0e0Nd8Ctf9LzRD5Zzhi4_oSBA#logs%5Fssh

Comment: Yes, what you are attempting often doesn't work, it depends on your router. Often they don't loop back from internal to external back to internal.Typically, we run an internal DNS so that the names resolve correctly for internal use.

Comment: Funny thing is I can do that to reach the Solus notebook. Just a change of the port number. Just from -p 2111 to -p 2113.

Comment: Oh!. Then yes I agree it should have worked. suggest you run tcpdump on the pi server and watch for the traffic at the packet level. Suggest: `sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -vvv -i enp2s0 port 22` . Change the interface name to yours. I do not know if you are forwarding port 2111 to port 22 or if your pi server is listening on port 2111. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: "I do not know if you are forwarding port 2111 to port 22 or if your pi server is listening on port 2111". First case. My router forwards from port 2111 to 22 for the server and 2113 to 22 for the Solus.

Comment: Well, I created some wireshark files if that helps. [link](icloud.com/iclouddrive/01EoOAREv-eXfJXGzy0ibNN7Q#Wireshark)

Comment: I am unable to access the files you posted. It wants me to log into iCloud. Please edit your question and put the stuff there. I'll format it, if you don't know how.

Comment: Those are wireshark files. Tried to open with a text editor and it was unreadable. Hope this link works: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hC1lpBJJVos3uX0DYBfuVhaMjitsw1p5?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry, I can not help you. maybe someone else will. I'm not going to do a lot of extra work just to look at what should have been maybe 50 lines of tcpdump capture in plain text. the one wireshark file I did look at didn't have any port 22 related traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had to stop dealing with that for a bit. Here are the results:
Windows -> Raspeberry Pi internal network (connection accepted)

```
sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -vvv -i wlan0 port 22
tcpdump: listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2021-03-10 21:50:05.687246 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58889, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [S], cksum 0xb3cd (correct), seq 1351350118, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.687776 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [S.], cksum 0xd536 (correct), seq 283168166, ack 1351350119, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.693230 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58890, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x0ef9 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.694852 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58891, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 72)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xaa23 (correct), seq 1:33, ack 1, win 513, length 32
2021-03-10 21:50:05.695076 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7943, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0x0ee4 (correct), seq 1, ack 33, win 502, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.730026 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7944, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 72)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xaa0e (correct), seq 1:33, ack 33, win 502, length 32
2021-03-10 21:50:05.738850 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58892, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x5ef3 (correct), seq 33:1493, ack 33, win 513, length 1460
2021-03-10 21:50:05.739080 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7945, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1096)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb353 (correct), seq 33:1089, ack 1493, win 501, length 1056
2021-03-10 21:50:05.739366 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58893, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 92)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0a8c (correct), seq 1493:1545, ack 33, win 513, length 52
2021-03-10 21:50:05.739436 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7946, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0x04bd (correct), seq 1089, ack 1545, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.746040 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58894, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 88)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x226f (correct), seq 1545:1593, ack 1089, win 509, length 48
2021-03-10 21:50:05.746298 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7947, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0x048d (correct), seq 1089, ack 1593, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.762828 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7948, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 548)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd285 (correct), seq 1089:1597, ack 1593, win 501, length 508
2021-03-10 21:50:05.770021 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58895, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x0285 (correct), seq 1593, ack 1597, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.771797 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58896, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 56)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xf84b (correct), seq 1593:1609, ack 1597, win 513, length 16
2021-03-10 21:50:05.771952 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7949, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0x0281 (correct), seq 1597, ack 1609, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.776487 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58897, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8aec (correct), seq 1609:1653, ack 1597, win 513, length 44
2021-03-10 21:50:05.776677 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7950, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0x0255 (correct), seq 1597, ack 1653, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:05.777219 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7951, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x577d (correct), seq 1597:1641, ack 1653, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 21:50:05.786629 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58898, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 108)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4c49 (correct), seq 1653:1721, ack 1641, win 513, length 68
2021-03-10 21:50:05.793370 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7952, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 92)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x92ed (correct), seq 1641:1693, ack 1721, win 501, length 52
2021-03-10 21:50:05.843085 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58899, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x01a6 (correct), seq 1721, ack 1693, win 512, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:10.363757 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58900, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 188)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x84f6 (correct), seq 1721:1869, ack 1693, win 512, length 148
2021-03-10 21:50:10.404879 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7953, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0x011d (correct), seq 1693, ack 1869, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:10.414224 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7954, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 68)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb8f7 (correct), seq 1693:1721, ack 1869, win 501, length 28
2021-03-10 21:50:10.417270 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58901, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 152)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd150 (correct), seq 1869:1981, ack 1721, win 512, length 112
2021-03-10 21:50:10.417525 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7955, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0x0091 (correct), seq 1721, ack 1981, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:10.982547 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7956, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 668)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xc038 (correct), seq 1721:2349, ack 1981, win 501, length 628
2021-03-10 21:50:11.042448 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58902, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe13 (correct), seq 1981, ack 2349, win 510, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:11.042760 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7957, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xdc9d (correct), seq 2349:2393, ack 1981, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 21:50:11.046351 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58903, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 492)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x7624 (correct), seq 1981:2433, ack 2393, win 510, length 452
2021-03-10 21:50:11.046551 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7958, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0xfc2c (correct), seq 2393, ack 2433, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:11.059750 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7959, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 148)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xab48 (correct), seq 2393:2501, ack 2433, win 501, length 108
2021-03-10 21:50:11.060627 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7960, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 492)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xad40 (correct), seq 2501:2953, ack 2433, win 501, length 452
2021-03-10 21:50:11.062617 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58904, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf9f6 (correct), seq 2433, ack 2953, win 507, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:11.923790 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7961, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 220)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x881a (correct), seq 2953:3133, ack 2433, win 501, length 180
2021-03-10 21:50:11.924368 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7962, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 108)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x67fb (correct), seq 3133:3201, ack 2433, win 501, length 68
2021-03-10 21:50:11.926999 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58905, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf8fe (correct), seq 2433, ack 3201, win 507, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:11.927165 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58906, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf8f8 (correct), seq 2433, ack 3201, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.082047 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7963, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa6a1 (correct), seq 3201:3245, ack 2433, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 21:50:12.113248 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7964, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 196)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x42b2 (correct), seq 3245:3401, ack 2433, win 501, length 156
2021-03-10 21:50:12.116077 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7965, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 176)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xcf6a (correct), seq 3401:3537, ack 2433, win 501, length 136
2021-03-10 21:50:12.118544 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58907, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf831 (correct), seq 2433, ack 3401, win 512, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.119602 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7966, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x604b (correct), seq 3537:3581, ack 2433, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 21:50:12.122118 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58908, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf77e (correct), seq 2433, ack 3581, win 511, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.203935 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7967, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 196)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1554 (correct), seq 3581:3737, ack 2433, win 501, length 156
2021-03-10 21:50:12.204908 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7968, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 132)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x2b84 (correct), seq 3737:3829, ack 2433, win 501, length 92
2021-03-10 21:50:12.207025 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58909, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf687 (correct), seq 2433, ack 3829, win 510, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.241845 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7969, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 196)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1e6d (correct), seq 3829:3985, ack 2433, win 501, length 156
2021-03-10 21:50:12.242979 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7970, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 132)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x730e (correct), seq 3985:4077, ack 2433, win 501, length 92
2021-03-10 21:50:12.245344 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58910, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf590 (correct), seq 2433, ack 4077, win 509, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.373823 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7971, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 252)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa07b (correct), seq 4077:4289, ack 2433, win 501, length 212
2021-03-10 21:50:12.434333 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58911, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf4bc (correct), seq 2433, ack 4289, win 509, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.442599 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58912, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 76)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x491f (correct), seq 2433:2469, ack 4289, win 509, length 36
2021-03-10 21:50:12.442740 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7972, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0xf4a0 (correct), seq 4289, ack 2469, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.443621 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7973, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 92)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8a45 (correct), seq 4289:4341, ack 2469, win 501, length 52
2021-03-10 21:50:12.467137 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7974, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 216)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd102 (correct), seq 4341:4517, ack 2469, win 501, length 176
2021-03-10 21:50:12.474837 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58913, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf3b5 (correct), seq 2469, ack 4517, win 508, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.475666 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58914, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 76)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa667 (correct), seq 2469:2505, ack 4517, win 508, length 36
2021-03-10 21:50:12.475759 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7975, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0xf398 (correct), seq 4517, ack 2505, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.476632 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58915, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1f37 (correct), seq 2505:2565, ack 4517, win 508, length 60
2021-03-10 21:50:12.476726 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7976, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0xf35c (correct), seq 4517, ack 2565, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.476791 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58916, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [F.], cksum 0xf354 (correct), seq 2565, ack 4517, win 508, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.520904 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7977, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [.], cksum 0xf35b (correct), seq 4517, ack 2566, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.522057 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 7978, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.105.22 > 192.168.1.103.62504: Flags [F.], cksum 0xf35a (correct), seq 4517, ack 2566, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 21:50:12.550803 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58917, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62504 > 192.168.1.105.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xf353 (correct), seq 2566, ack 4518, win 508, length 0
```

Windows -> Raspberry Pi using DDNS (not working)

```
sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -vvv -i wlan0 port 22
tcpdump: listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

So, definitely it is not getting there. Gotta get my Solus notebook and run the same command and check the differences. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And here are the logs from my Solus notebook 
Windows -> Solus using internal network:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -vvv -i wlp5s0 port 22
tcpdump: listening on wlp5s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2021-03-10 22:39:34.071511 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23708, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [S], cksum 0x7b57 (correct), seq 3936130434, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.071662 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [S.], cksum 0x08bc (correct), seq 3206460268, ack 3936130435, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.077639 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23709, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x427e (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.077801 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23710, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 72)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xdda8 (correct), seq 1:33, ack 1, win 513, length 32
2021-03-10 22:39:34.077849 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38405, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [.], cksum 0x4269 (correct), seq 1, ack 33, win 502, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.103273 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38406, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 61)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x7da3 (correct), seq 1:22, ack 33, win 502, length 21
2021-03-10 22:39:34.106991 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23711, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x497b (correct), seq 33:1493, ack 22, win 513, length 1460
2021-03-10 22:39:34.107083 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38407, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1064)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x98b6 (correct), seq 22:1046, ack 1493, win 501, length 1024
2021-03-10 22:39:34.108408 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23712, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 92)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x3e1c (correct), seq 1493:1545, ack 22, win 513, length 52
2021-03-10 22:39:34.108546 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38408, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [.], cksum 0x386d (correct), seq 1046, ack 1545, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.113863 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23713, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 88)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4d10 (correct), seq 1545:1593, ack 1046, win 509, length 48
2021-03-10 22:39:34.113943 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38409, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [.], cksum 0x383d (correct), seq 1046, ack 1593, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.154690 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38410, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1204)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x2653 (correct), seq 1046:2210, ack 1593, win 501, length 1164
2021-03-10 22:39:34.158209 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23714, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x33a5 (correct), seq 1593, ack 2210, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.164395 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23715, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 56)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x296c (correct), seq 1593:1609, ack 2210, win 513, length 16
2021-03-10 22:39:34.164478 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38411, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [.], cksum 0x33a1 (correct), seq 2210, ack 1609, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.167976 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23716, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xaece (correct), seq 1609:1653, ack 2210, win 513, length 44
2021-03-10 22:39:34.168080 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38412, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [.], cksum 0x3375 (correct), seq 2210, ack 1653, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:34.168394 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38413, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0cc5 (correct), seq 2210:2254, ack 1653, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:39:34.173792 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23717, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 108)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa529 (correct), seq 1653:1721, ack 2254, win 513, length 68
2021-03-10 22:39:34.179849 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38414, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 116)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5bd0 (correct), seq 2254:2330, ack 1721, win 501, length 76
2021-03-10 22:39:34.183466 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23718, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 132)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x726f (correct), seq 1721:1813, ack 2330, win 512, length 92
2021-03-10 22:39:34.189371 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38415, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 116)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x505d (correct), seq 2330:2406, ack 1813, win 501, length 76
2021-03-10 22:39:34.237893 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23719, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x3206 (correct), seq 1813, ack 2406, win 512, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:39.248208 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23720, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 188)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x3807 (correct), seq 1813:1961, ack 2406, win 512, length 148
2021-03-10 22:39:39.270583 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38416, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 68)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4fea (correct), seq 2406:2434, ack 1961, win 501, length 28
2021-03-10 22:39:39.277177 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23721, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 152)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0cfd (correct), seq 1961:2073, ack 2434, win 512, length 112
2021-03-10 22:39:39.277317 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38417, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 508)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x738f (correct), seq 2434:2902, ack 2073, win 501, length 468
2021-03-10 22:39:39.331573 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23722, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x2f14 (correct), seq 2073, ack 2902, win 510, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:39.331703 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38418, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x6359 (correct), seq 2902:2946, ack 2073, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:39:39.336341 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23723, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 492)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x126d (correct), seq 2073:2525, ack 2946, win 510, length 452
2021-03-10 22:39:39.339175 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38419, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 148)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x082d (correct), seq 2946:3054, ack 2525, win 501, length 108
2021-03-10 22:39:39.339516 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38420, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 132)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x88c4 (correct), seq 3054:3146, ack 2525, win 501, length 92
2021-03-10 22:39:39.345412 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23724, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x2c5d (correct), seq 2525, ack 3146, win 509, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:39.391673 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38421, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 860)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x397c (correct), seq 3146:3966, ack 2525, win 501, length 820
2021-03-10 22:39:39.397388 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23725, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x2925 (correct), seq 2525, ack 3966, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:40.138688 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38422, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8fe8 (correct), seq 3966:4010, ack 2525, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:39:40.139371 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38423, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 108)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x2407 (correct), seq 4010:4078, ack 2525, win 501, length 68
2021-03-10 22:39:40.142304 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23726, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x28b6 (correct), seq 2525, ack 4078, win 512, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:40.143271 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38424, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x12e7 (correct), seq 4078:4138, ack 2525, win 501, length 60
2021-03-10 22:39:40.143773 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38425, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 284)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5e0a (correct), seq 4138:4382, ack 2525, win 501, length 244
2021-03-10 22:39:40.147812 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23727, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x2787 (correct), seq 2525, ack 4382, win 511, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:40.152648 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38426, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 676)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x31ed (correct), seq 4382:5018, ack 2525, win 501, length 636
2021-03-10 22:39:40.153072 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38427, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0916 (correct), seq 5018:5062, ack 2525, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:39:40.157882 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38428, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 92)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9fca (correct), seq 5062:5114, ack 2525, win 501, length 52
2021-03-10 22:39:40.158338 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38429, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5e90 (correct), seq 5114:5158, ack 2525, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:39:40.159438 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23728, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x24e1 (correct), seq 2525, ack 5062, win 509, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:40.163055 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23729, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x2482 (correct), seq 2525, ack 5158, win 508, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:41.137319 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23730, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 76)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xab40 (correct), seq 2525:2561, ack 5158, win 508, length 36
2021-03-10 22:39:41.138289 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38430, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 92)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0x59f5 (correct), seq 5158:5210, ack 2561, win 501, length 52
2021-03-10 22:39:41.149207 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38431, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 216)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [P.], cksum 0xe56a (correct), seq 5210:5386, ack 2561, win 501, length 176
2021-03-10 22:39:41.154374 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23731, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x237b (correct), seq 2561, ack 5386, win 507, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:41.154442 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23732, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 76)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xbbaf (correct), seq 2561:2597, ack 5386, win 507, length 36
2021-03-10 22:39:41.157787 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23733, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x751e (correct), seq 2597:2657, ack 5386, win 507, length 60
2021-03-10 22:39:41.157846 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23734, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [F.], cksum 0x231a (correct), seq 2657, ack 5386, win 507, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:41.157951 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38432, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [.], cksum 0x2320 (correct), seq 5386, ack 2658, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:41.160147 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 38433, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 192.168.1.103.62569: Flags [F.], cksum 0x231f (correct), seq 5386, ack 2658, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:39:41.165223 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23735, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.103.62569 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x2319 (correct), seq 2658, ack 5387, win 507, length 0
```

Windows -> Solus using DDNS (it takes longer as the connection is established when it switches to IPv4:

```
    sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -vvv -i wlp5s0 port 22
tcpdump: listening on wlp5s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2021-03-10 22:43:28.374349 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16482, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [S], cksum 0xf0a7 (correct), seq 1211222795, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.374513 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [S.], cksum 0xe3c9 (correct), seq 827054978, ack 1211222796, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.378533 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16483, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x1d8c (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.396567 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16484, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 72)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb8b6 (correct), seq 1:33, ack 1, win 513, length 32
2021-03-10 22:43:28.396640 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10273, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [.], cksum 0x1d77 (correct), seq 1, ack 33, win 502, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.404029 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10274, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 61)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x58b1 (correct), seq 1:22, ack 33, win 502, length 21
2021-03-10 22:43:28.419322 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16485, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x69f3 (correct), seq 33:1493, ack 22, win 513, length 1460
2021-03-10 22:43:28.419574 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10275, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1064)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0a51 (correct), seq 22:1046, ack 1493, win 501, length 1024
2021-03-10 22:43:28.419666 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16486, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 116)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9d6c (correct), seq 1493:1569, ack 22, win 513, length 76
2021-03-10 22:43:28.419724 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10276, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [.], cksum 0x1363 (correct), seq 1046, ack 1569, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.443638 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16487, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 88)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x6fa3 (correct), seq 1569:1617, ack 1046, win 509, length 48
2021-03-10 22:43:28.443795 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10277, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [.], cksum 0x1333 (correct), seq 1046, ack 1617, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.484682 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10278, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1204)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x15f8 (correct), seq 1046:2210, ack 1617, win 501, length 1164
2021-03-10 22:43:28.489015 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16488, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x0e9b (correct), seq 1617, ack 2210, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.497677 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16489, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 56)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0462 (correct), seq 1617:1633, ack 2210, win 513, length 16
2021-03-10 22:43:28.538274 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10279, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [.], cksum 0x0e97 (correct), seq 2210, ack 1633, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.540717 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16490, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9a72 (correct), seq 1633:1677, ack 2210, win 513, length 44
2021-03-10 22:43:28.540774 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10280, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [.], cksum 0x0e6b (correct), seq 2210, ack 1677, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.541052 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10281, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x320e (correct), seq 2210:2254, ack 1677, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:43:28.545552 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16491, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 108)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xbe38 (correct), seq 1677:1745, ack 2254, win 513, length 68
2021-03-10 22:43:28.545637 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10282, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [.], cksum 0x0dfb (correct), seq 2254, ack 1745, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.551585 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10283, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 116)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x19f2 (correct), seq 2254:2330, ack 1745, win 501, length 76
2021-03-10 22:43:28.561822 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16492, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 132)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd7e2 (correct), seq 1745:1837, ack 2330, win 512, length 92
2021-03-10 22:43:28.561962 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10284, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [.], cksum 0x0d53 (correct), seq 2330, ack 1837, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:28.567857 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10285, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 116)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x09f2 (correct), seq 2330:2406, ack 1837, win 501, length 76
2021-03-10 22:43:28.616463 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16493, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x0cfc (correct), seq 1837, ack 2406, win 512, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:34.128323 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16494, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 188)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x439c (correct), seq 1837:1985, ack 2406, win 512, length 148
2021-03-10 22:43:34.150835 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10286, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 68)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9465 (correct), seq 2406:2434, ack 1985, win 501, length 28
2021-03-10 22:43:34.158065 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16495, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 152)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xaaad (correct), seq 1985:2097, ack 2434, win 512, length 112
2021-03-10 22:43:34.158216 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10287, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 508)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1937 (correct), seq 2434:2902, ack 2097, win 501, length 468
2021-03-10 22:43:34.209526 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16496, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x0a0a (correct), seq 2097, ack 2902, win 510, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:34.209665 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10288, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x28a9 (correct), seq 2902:2946, ack 2097, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:43:34.226961 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16497, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 492)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x6074 (correct), seq 2097:2549, ack 2946, win 510, length 452
2021-03-10 22:43:34.230547 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10289, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 148)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x28e0 (correct), seq 2946:3054, ack 2549, win 501, length 108
2021-03-10 22:43:34.231238 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10290, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 132)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x29b9 (correct), seq 3054:3146, ack 2549, win 501, length 92
2021-03-10 22:43:34.236873 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16498, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x0753 (correct), seq 2549, ack 3146, win 509, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:34.282774 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10291, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 852)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0357 (correct), seq 3146:3958, ack 2549, win 501, length 812
2021-03-10 22:43:34.287527 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16499, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x0423 (correct), seq 2549, ack 3958, win 513, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:34.831265 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10292, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd246 (correct), seq 3958:4002, ack 2549, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:43:34.831961 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10293, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 108)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9a86 (correct), seq 4002:4070, ack 2549, win 501, length 68
2021-03-10 22:43:34.835951 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10294, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd82a (correct), seq 4070:4130, ack 2549, win 501, length 60
2021-03-10 22:43:34.836749 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10295, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 284)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x011e (correct), seq 4130:4374, ack 2549, win 501, length 244
2021-03-10 22:43:34.841676 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16500, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x0285 (correct), seq 2549, ack 4374, win 511, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:34.845786 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10296, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 676)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x20d6 (correct), seq 4374:5010, ack 2549, win 501, length 636
2021-03-10 22:43:34.846305 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10297, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8157 (correct), seq 5010:5054, ack 2549, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:43:34.849435 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16501, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xffde (correct), seq 2549, ack 5054, win 509, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:34.851311 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10298, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 92)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1aab (correct), seq 5054:5106, ack 2549, win 501, length 52
2021-03-10 22:43:34.851792 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10299, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x7438 (correct), seq 5106:5150, ack 2549, win 501, length 44
2021-03-10 22:43:34.870326 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16502, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xff7f (correct), seq 2549, ack 5150, win 508, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:37.498189 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16503, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 76)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb0c8 (correct), seq 2549:2585, ack 5150, win 508, length 36
2021-03-10 22:43:37.498971 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10300, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 92)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa61d (correct), seq 5150:5202, ack 2585, win 501, length 52
2021-03-10 22:43:37.512089 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10301, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 216)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [P.], cksum 0x57d6 (correct), seq 5202:5378, ack 2585, win 501, length 176
2021-03-10 22:43:37.516471 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16504, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe78 (correct), seq 2585, ack 5378, win 507, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:37.530262 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16505, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 76)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0b04 (correct), seq 2585:2621, ack 5378, win 507, length 36
2021-03-10 22:43:37.531763 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16506, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [P.], cksum 0x77dd (correct), seq 2621:2681, ack 5378, win 507, length 60
2021-03-10 22:43:37.531891 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10302, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe1e (correct), seq 5378, ack 2681, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:37.533240 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16507, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [F.], cksum 0xfe17 (correct), seq 2681, ack 5378, win 507, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:37.534614 IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 10303, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.113.22 > 101.112.84.13.62605: Flags [F.], cksum 0xfe1c (correct), seq 5378, ack 2682, win 501, length 0
2021-03-10 22:43:37.538714 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16508, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    101.112.84.13.62605 > 192.168.1.113.22: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe16 (correct), seq 2682, ack 5379, win 507, length 0
```

Hope this info can be helpful. Thanks